Attempt at an Analysis Question. Unsure of rigour
I am currently looking at differentiation in Real Analysis and attempting the following question:

Suppose that $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are functions with $f$ differentiable and $g(0) = g(1) = 0.$ Suppose furthermore that : $g(x)f'(x) + f(x) = 1 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Show that if $0 \le a < b \le 1$ then there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = 1.$

It also gives a hint that you can use a proof by contradiction and consider the properties of the sets $\{x \in [0,a] \cup [b, 1] : f(x) = 1\}$.
It is simple to show that there is some c that satisfies this within 0 and 1 using Rolle's Theorem, then you can repeat this infinitely many times due to the condition given until the points for which f(x) = 1 approach a and b as it repeats infinitely in a worst case scenario. But is this enough to prove the theorem ? I have a feeling that this is not strong enough and I am struggling to see how to make it more rigourous.
Thank you

The statement
"if $0 \le a < b \le 1$ then there is some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) =1$"
states that $f$ equals $1$ on a dense subset of $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is continuous the conclusion is that $f$ is identically equal to $1$ on $[0,1]$.
